# Is there a CMIS server available that is not running on Java?

Tags: adobe, alfresco, cmis, crx, nuxeo

I tried the usual:

1. [CRX](http://www.day.com/day/en.html) from Day.com: not (yet) stable
2. [KnowledgeTree Community](http://www.knowledgetree.org/Main_Page): couldn't get it to work (unless perhaps you buy the commercial version?)
3. [Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.com/en/downloads/download-dm-form): very, very expensive, but looks good (is there a community version available?)
4. yet a few more

I also installed [Alfresco](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Download_Labs), which seems to be the best out there in terms of functions it offers; I'm quite impressed by it, to be honest. However, it's very slow, sometimes taking a few minutes to check-in a document. It also takes quite a lot of memory (maybe due to Java?). It also has some issues dealing with Illustrator documents.

Is there a CMIS server available that can connect to Adobe Drive (CMIS) and not running on Java?

I just need the Check-in/out functions through Adobe Drive 2.1 or 3.0 CMIS.

**UPDATE [20/02/2012]**
After playing with the above-mentioned software for a while, I can (personally) affirm that Alfresco is the best among all (free) available software. I'm running the community version 4.0.d. It seems pretty stable and the installation + connexion to Adobe Drive 3.0.1 via the CMIS connector is seamless; (FYI in Drive: cmis://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/service/cmis).

**UPDATE [25/06/2014]**
@NicolasRaoul is right. CMIS **not** running on Java, as specified in the title => Nuxeo. Hence @JulienCarsique's answer accepted/upvoted.

Comment: PS: Your Link has been added.

Comment: Alfresco shouldn't be that slow, and if you're using 4.0a then it'll work just fine with Illustrator documents. I'd suggest you check your Alfresco setup

Comment: Running on a Mac Mini Server Quad-Core with 8Gb Ram. Still, it's slow, much slower than Adobe Drive 2.1 + CUE CS4. I'll try 4.0a shortly (I think I'm running 4.0 if not wrong.)

Comment: Like Gagravarr is saying, it shouldn't run that slow. I've seen the CMIS server of Alfresco performing good on less powerful servers. It might have something to do with your installation/setup

Comment: Thanks Tahir, but it's an install out the box. The server is running nothing special. Not sure what kind of tuning I could do here. One thing though, the number of files in CUE is pretty large. That might be part of the reason. So, if I understand correctly, there is Adobe Drive 2.1 with CUE CS4, or Adobe Drive 3.0 with Alfresco. There is nothing else on the market that does **not** run on Java, is that right?

Comment: @Gagravarr, it is indeed faster with 4.0.d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About Nuxeo, it is free for use. There's no "community" or "enterprise" versions but a unique Open-Source, free and enterprise-ready version.

Comment: Julien, it seems to me that Nuxeo [isn't free](http://www.nuxeo.com/en/downloads). They let you install the full package, but limited to 30 days. This is what's said during the install:
`**SET UP**
... The 6th step in the configuration process enables you to subscribe to a free 30 day trial offer of Nuxeo Connect, giving you access to Nuxeo Studio and the Nuxeo Marketplace to adapt the Nuxeo Platform to your specific needs.
If you're not ready to try this offer, feel free to skip it. You can start your Nuxeo Connect and Nuxeo Studio trial at any time...`

Comment: from their download page: `You can download or access an online trial of the same version of Nuxeo software used for full-scale deployments, right here, right now. We don’t distinguish between a “free” and an “enterprise” version - we want you to experience the full power of the Nuxeo technology from the first stages of your engagement with us.`

Comment: See [that answer](http://answers.nuxeo.com/questions/1043/is-nuxeo-open-source) for full details. Nuxeo Connect and Nuxeo Studio are non-free online services provided by Nuxeo. They are not required for using Nuxeo which is fully free for download and for use, and not limited in time.

Comment: From my understanding (as of 2017), you can still use the Nuxeo Studio after the trial expired. Just won't get the updates anymore. I read it somewhere in the Nuxeo forums. Don't have the link at hand right now.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, there is a CMIS implementation that is not based on Java. It is Microsoft Sharepoint, which also has a CMIS connector. I don't know anything about it's completeness or  performance.

Something tells me though that is not the platform you are looking for and it will definitely not run on your Mac Mini.

Comment: SharePoint Foundation does not support CMIS. You will need the expensive so-called "SharePoint Server" product. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/which-sharepoint-versions-support-cmis

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the above-mentioned software for a while, I can (personally) affirm that Alfresco is the best among all (free) available software. I'm running the community version 4.0.d. It seems pretty stable and the installation + connexion to Adobe Drive 3.0.1 via the CMIS connector is seamless; (FYI in Drive: cmis://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/service/cmis).

Comment: While I agree that Alfresco is the greatest CMIS server, this answer does not match the question you asked: "Is there a CMIS server available that is not running on Java?". You should accept Julien's answer.